# filtering multiple values in json data to use in D3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a list of checkboxes and i'm saving all checked values in an array -> selected_prospect_array.

I'm trying to filter a json object array to return only the values that are in selected_prospect_array.

I want to use the filtered json to generate D3 circles.

This is how I initially set up the loop: loop through  selected_prospect_array ->filter in d3 -> draw bubble and start the process again.

The only problem is it only draws the first bubble; It seems to stop looping after it draws the first bubble.

My code looks like that:

```
for (i = 0; i < selected_prospect_array.length; i++) {
              var tempdata;

               var val = selected_prospect_array[i];

                tempdata = filteredjson.filter(function (d) { return d.ProspectName == val; });


              g.selectAll("circle").data(tempdata).enter().append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return x_scale(d.PercentageComplete * 100) })
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y_scale(d.GPoS * 100) })
      .attr("r", "30")
      .attr("stroke", "blue")
     .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr("opacity", 0.6)
      .attr("fill", "red");


      }
```

Any other way to do this? can i filter the json file directly?

Comment: Is your condition is properly evaluated in return statement... I hope it returns true or false rather than the data

Comment: the condition is properly evaluated, return d.ProspectName == val returns the correct value. the problem seems to be on the D3 side but i'm not sure how to get around this